# Consent with the User Messaging Platform not saved

Tags: android

I implemented [Consent with the User Messaging Platform](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start). It works very well except one thing. I must provide to user option to change values, for that I used following code:

```
private void showForm(Activity activity, ConsentForm consentForm) {
    consentForm.show(
            activity,
            new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                    // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                    loadForm(activity, false);
                }
            });
}
```

But problem is that no matter what I set in that form, it always opens with "default" values. I do not get any errors. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you found what's wrong?

Comment: Nope and support doesn´t understand problem, not sure why.